# How to use fade in/out in my jQuery for slideshow to text

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code I tried using:

```
<div class"text><p>life is the best gift of nature</p>
<p>will were born to be the best</p>
```

Then in my jQuery in my app.js file:

```
$('.text').fadeOut(5000).addClass('.text').fadeIn(5000);
```

Comment: Is expected result for text "life is the best gift of nature" to fade out ,  text "will were born to be the best" to fade in ?

Comment: 1st problem: `addClass()` should not contain any `.`. 2nd problem: Why are you adding a "text" class to an element which already has a "text" class?

Comment: @DanielCheung: I unrolled your edit because the jQuery code is entirely useless without the HTML that it references. The code is exactly what the OP posted, except that it wasn't formatted properly as code. Check the "side-by-side markdown" in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31228954/revisions) for details.

Comment: @NisseEngström Your edit affects the answer. You would not know OP's code. Are you sure the first two texts are even put in a `<p>` or `<div>`?

Comment: @DanielCheung: Pretty sure. The revision history has a link to the [original source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11e6bfe4-dee8-4ec8-a150-ff5afdb84e8b/view-source) of the post. It's right there.

Comment: @DanielCheung: As my edit summary says, I cross-checked the revision history. I'm reasonably confident, independent of anyone else, that the code in its present form is an accurate representation of the querent's code... barring any typos introduced on their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

JS:

```
$('.text').fadeOut(5000, function(){
    $('.text').text("will were born to be the best").fadeIn(5000);
})
```

There is another function argument within `fadeOut()` because that is a "callback" function. It will execute only after the fading is finished.

HTML:

```
<p class="text">life is the best gift of nature</p>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('.text').fadeOut(5000, function(){
        $('.text').text("will were born to be the best").fadeIn(5000);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">life is the best gift of nature</p>
```